# Can Adobe Air Run Normally on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, flash, macos

I've heard Adobe Air is "native" but I also heard that Apple does everything to make it near impossible to get Air to run on iOS.

Can you make an Air app that runs on both Android and iOS but which will run on iOS without having to install a ton of crazy SKD's on iPhone and such?

I've got an Air app to run perfectly on my Android but the iPhone is an entirely different story.

Are there any resources that explain this issue?

Comment: From what i know flash doesn't work on iOS unless the device is jailbreaked.

Comment: Please make it more clear what your actual question is. It seems like you're asking how to port an Adobe Air app to iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile AIR apps as stand-alone apps for iOS. The AIR runtime as such can not be installed on iOS, instead each app is stand-alone.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/ios.html

And for the record, it is not Flash or AIR as such that is not allowed on iOS, by Apple, no browser plugins are allowed (Mobile Safari doesn't support plugins), and no third-party runtimes, for example Java.

Comment: +1 It is the iOS security model that prevents AIR from running outside of a standalone app. As noted, this eliminates a lot of modular software such as Java or browser plugins. iOS is designed to be secure before all other considerations and that is a design tradeoff. Android is more flexible but less secure. There have already been several exploits of Android but none for iOS.  Security and flexibility/openness are innately antithetical.

Comment: So they basically the flash player along with the app, and thus it allows Flash apps to work on iOS?

Comment: Yes, the player and the app specific code are combined into one binary.